# declare $var_1 = $var_2 inside a class

Tags: php

Is there a way to declare something like `$session_username = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];` in a php class, so I can use $session_username in every methods inside this class ?

This is I don't have to declare again my variables names in every methods.

Manuals tell me that I can only declare a variable if this one is "simple", like a string or a number, otherwise I am getting a parse error. I also tried declaring it as a constante or a public variable but as far as I understand it doesn't work that way.

What is the correct way to do this ?

**edit :** Thanks for your explanations.
Here is an exemple of what I end up with right now (a few things left to understand)

```
new session_auth();

class session_auth{

    public $sessionID; // php session variable for id
    public $sessionUSERNAME; // php session variable for username


    public function VarSession() {
    $this->sessionID = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['id']; // php session variable for id
    $this->sessionUSERNAME = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username']; // php session variable for username
    }

    function is_user_logged_in() {
        if (!empty($this->sessionUSERNAME) && $this->sessionUSERNAME != 'guest') {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

So I declare my variables in the php class. Then I define my variables inside the function `VarSession()`. However as it is I'm not able to use them is the function `is_user_logged_in()` is this correct ?

Comment: Learn about class properties: `$this->session_username = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];` in your constructor

Comment: Your code should work, as long as your call `VarSession()` before `is_user_logged_in()`, otherwise the class properties would be empty still. But your variable names are wrong... `$this->sessionID` should be `$this->session_id`

Comment: Allrigh thank you, yes I changed `session_id` to `sessionID` last second because it appeared `session_id` is already a native php function. It should be fine now. Last thing, I am familiar with initializing VarSession from outside of the class (before calling my methods) but it be initialized automatically, inside the class ? Or this that where class constructors are useful. Anyways thank for your help, setting this as solved !

Comment: Yes you should look into the `__construct` method. It is built into PHP and it is a method which will be called when the class is instantiated, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the variable as a property on your class like this:

```
class Helloworld
{
    // Create your class property
    public $sessionUsername;

    public function helloWorld()
    {
        // Set your class property
        $this->sessionUsername = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];
    }
}
```

Then you can access it throughout your class by doing this:

```
$this->sessionUsername
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is the first time I'm gonna use this method to declare variables so a few questions : Do I need to call the function hellowWorld before I can use `$this->sessionUsername` in other functions of this class ? And basically, the function helloWorld will be used only to declare the variables that I need is that correct ? Can I declare as much variables as I need inside it, and call them the same way ?

Comment: Ignore the `helloWorld()` method it was just an example. However yes you will need to set the property before you can use it elsewhere, otherwise it will still be `undefined`. You should probably set the class properties in your `__construct` method.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to update my main post in a couple minutes to present what I have now after your advices if you don't mind having a look at it. Also what does "// Set your class property" means exactly in your exemple ? How do I set the class property, does php already know which class we are in ? Thanks again

Comment: It is a comment which describes what the line below it is doing. `$this->sessionUsername = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];` will set `$sessionUsername` to be `$_SESSION['simple_auth']['username']`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a property of the object/class called `username`

```
private $username = null;
```

and initiate a username with a class constructor `__constructor` so that everytime the class is called, username also initialized.

**For example**

```
class ClassName extends AnotherClass {
  private $username = null;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->username = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];
  }

  public function get () {
    return $this->username;
  }
}
```

and create a function `get` which is getter of the class, to properly get the value of the instance of a class called `username`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not very familiar with class constructors, this is new to me I'm gonna have to check this out. Are they just regular functions (like VarSession in edit) or are they a specific php function ?

Comment: A special type of subroutine which mean to create an object, like for example $obj = new Classname(); a constructor is responsible that $obj can have all class properties. Check this out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 1):

```
class abc{
    private $variable = "test"
    public function function1(){
         echo $this->variable;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help!